# How can you deserialize a JSON array containing different types in .Net?

Tags: c#, json, serialization, types

I'm trying to deserialize a JSON object array in C#. The array represents a row of a table, mainly consisting of plain strings. However, one or more of the items in the array may not be a string but infact a JSON object in itself, e.g.

```
"rows":[[{"date":"20140521","category":"one"},"data","moredata","evenmoredata"],...]
```

or on a different response from the server, the order may be different

```
"rows":[["data","moredata",{"date":"20140521","category":"one"},"evenmoredata"],...]
```

I'm trying to just treat this as a list of objects, with a known type called RowObject below:

```
[DataContract]
[KnownType(typeof(RowObject))]
public class Table
{
    // other members to deserialize

    [DataMember(Name = "rows")]
    public List<List<object>> Rows { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class RowObject
{
    [DataMember(Name = "date")]
    public DateTime date { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "category")]
    public string category { get; set; }
}
```

This approach kind of worked in that the plain strings in the row were deserialized, however the RowObjects do not seem to be recognised even though I have tried to put them down as a `KnownType`. When I look at my deserialized `List<object>` Row, the RowObject just seems to be a blank object shown as `{object}` in the debugger.

I've managed to do this with known types and derived types elsewhere in the project but this problem dealing with plain strings has got me stuck. I've had a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3902826/deserializing-a-json-array-of-mixed-types) which seems pretty similar, but my problem with this answer is that I don't know which elements in the list are going to be the complex type. Also, I'm just using the .Net `DataContractJsonSerializer` throughout the project so would like to avoid third party libraries if at all possible.

Is it possible to deserialize a JSON array of different types like this?

Comment: Is it possible to clear out the non complex type members of the list, and afterwards process it as need be? Just put the other members in a different array for each type or discard as needed? Then use the list's sorting method.

Comment: How do you expect a serializer to deserialize to RowObject, if there is no type information in your json string of whatsoever?

Comment: I guess I was naively hoping that if the serializer saw it had some known types it would try to make a RowObject instead of the "base class" object. Not as easy as that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `EmitTypeInformation` in DataContractJsonSerializerSettings to `EmitTypeInformation.Always` on the server side. That way you will get information about the types of your objexts, inside the json string.

Comment: Thanks for this. I couldn't change the server side to do this exactly as per your answer, but it helped a lot. In the end the server now sends across a separate list containing the type information and I wrote a custom deserializer with JSON.Net to populate my List<object> with the right types.